# A Gatsby page is not getting created by gatsby at all no matter what I do it seems

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm very experienced with using NextJS which is similar to Gatsby, especially in the navigation structure and routing side of things...

However, I'm getting the strangest error ever PERTAINING ONLY TO MY shirts page which I have clearly created, you can see in the screenshot here [image]

All the other pages i.e. contact, hats, hoodies all work as expected flawlessly..

I've played around with this for over an hour, have deleted my node_modules, reinstalled npm, stopped running the server on the backend, stopped running gatsby on the frontend, restarted everything at least ten times and am still getting this strange 404 error that definitely makes zero sense since I have already created the shirts page as you can see in the screenshot link above... this is the error i'm getting... PLEASE HELP SOMEBODY ANYBODY...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page (`/shirts`) is created correctly since it appears in the 404 list of pages. Although Gatsby is not able to render it due to some React issue, it seems that everything ok in the code.

Keeping in mind what you have tried so far, I would recommend running `gatsby clean` (if you haven't already). In addition, I would get rid of the `shirts copy.js` page, just in case (because of the whitespace).

As a final attempt, you can try using the suggested snippet:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function ShirtsPage(){
  return <div>Hello</div>
}
```

Comment: wow. gatsby clean finally did it. thank you so much. amazing!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. `gatsby clean` is quite a useful command when weird stuff happens (normally related to cache). If the issue has been solved please consider accepting the answer to close the issue